# Closure of compactly supported functions a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that the normed linear space of bounded continuous functions, $\mathcal C_b(X)$, and the closure of compactly supported smooth test functions, $\mathcal C_0(X)$ are each a Banach space.

I have already proved $\mathcal C_b(X)$ is a Banach space by showing completeness.  I imagine I can prove $\mathcal C_0(X)$ is  Banach space by showing it is a subspace of $\mathcal C_b(X)$.  I know the three conditions I would have to prove, but how do I prove them for $\mathcal C_0(X)$?

Comment: What do you mean by test functions?

Comment: What are your norms?

Comment: With respect to the uniform norm.